# Drawing a graph from a function

Tags: c++, graph, functional-programming

I have a complex mathematical C++ function. I want a translated and easy to read graph out of it. Is there any software which can analyze special mathematical functions and draw an easy to read graph?  Assume it's an encryption algorithm code.

I have tried a lot of software like Understand, WizGraph, etc. Is there something I should search for to find this type of software?

Comment: What kind of graph?  Call graph?  Bar graph?

Answer (score 4):

Print the (x, y) values on `cout`, one pair (or tuple) of values per line, separated by commas.  Run the gen program from command interpreter, redirect to textfile `data.csv`.

Load the comma-separated values text file in Excel or other spreadsheet program.  Select the relevant data.  Graph it.

Comment: Not only is this the easiest way, but your end-users may prefer it since this the tool they're used to.

Comment: I don't want to have call graph or printing (x,y) pairs etc. It's an advanced encryption algorithm and I want it's graph, I mean flowchart in easy to read/understand format

Comment: @Martin, you weren't very clear about that, you may want to edit the question to get better answers. P.S. I'm embarrassed about my previous comment, I don't usually leave word out.